# Apache Pulsar implementation in a distributed system

Tags: apache-pulsar

I'm new to Apache Pulsar technology and I want to implement the Apache Pulsar in distributed system. In which one machine should have Pulsar Producer which produces the messages to the topic and the other machine should have Pulsar Consumer to consume those messages from the same topic.

Is there any way to implement the same using C# language.

Kindly help me with the guideline to implement it!

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please note that Stack Overflow is not made to ask for tutorial, video or book/technologie recommendation. Please use Stack Overflow to get help with code and see [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

There is a client library for C# linked in the official docs for Apache Pulsar:
https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/next/client-libraries-dotnet/

You'll find examples for producers and consumers there.